# Modify the value of only one element of a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, format, append

I would like to convert only one element of a list from string to float.

The list is:

```
list_1 = ['0.49', '0.54', '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54']
```

and the output I desire is:

```
list_2= ['0.49', 0.54, '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54']
```

By the code:

```
list_1 = ['0.49', '0.54', '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54']
list_2 = []
for element in list_1:
   if element == list_1[2]:
         list_2.append(float(element))
   else:
       list_2.append(element)
print(list_2)
```

the output is;

```
list_2= ['0.49', 0.54, 0.54, '0.55', '0.55', 0.54, '0.55', '0.55', 0.54]
```

Comment: Simply copy the list (`list2 = list1.copy()` for example), then convert its 2nd el: `list2[1] = float(list2[1])`

Comment: Why compare each item to `list1[2]` if you only want to modify this single item?? Just do `list_1[2] = float[list_1[2])`?

Comment: What exactly is the criterion for converting the list value from a string to a number? Is it that its index is 1? Is it that its value is `'0.54'` (but then why only one of them, and why the first one)?

Answer (score 1):

Simply make a copy of the original list and modify the element at index `1`:

```py
list_2 = [*list_1]
list_2[1] = float(list_2[1])
```

A list comprehension with `enumerate` can also be used.

```py
list_2 = [float(x) if i == 1 else x for i, x in enumerate(list_1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you may try to set a *flag* to mark the completed operation. Like this way:  (this is to follow your *thinking logic)*

Note - this is not based on the assumption of the `0.54` in the *fixed* position, prob. more *flexible.*

```py
list_2 = []
converted = False         # flag to check

for element in list_1:
    if element == '0.54' and not converted:
        list_2.append(float(element))
        converted = True
    else:
        list_2.append(element)

print(list_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the item you want to convert is based on a position, you can assign the converted value directly:

```
list_2 = list_1.copy()
list_2[1] = float(list_2[1])
```

If you are looking to convert the first occurrence of a given value, you can find the position using the index() method

```
list_2 = list_1.copy()
if '0.54' in list_2:
   index = list_2.index('0.54')
   list_2[index] = float(list_2[index])
```

You could use a dictionary to convert the first instance in a comprehension by using .pop() to remove the key after its first use:

```
convert = {'0.54':float }

list_2 = [convert.pop(s,str)(s) for s in list_1]
```

Using a dictionary like this lets you perform this one-time conversion on multiple values.  for example,if you're looking to convert the first instance of every string value, you can initialize the dictionary with the values themselves:

```
convert = dict.fromkeys(list_1,float)

list_2 = [convert.pop(s,str)(s) for s in list_1]

[0.49, 0.54, '0.54', 0.55, '0.55', '0.54', '0.55', '0.55', '0.54']
```